# Join two dynamic Linq in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, linq

I have used linq to store data, below is the code:

```
 var result = (dynamic)null;
 var serviceData = (dynamic)null;
 var userData = (dynamic)null;

 /****Linq 1*****/
serviceData= dtPasscode.AsEnumerable().Select(m => new
{
  ACCOUNT_ID = intAccountId,
  SUB_ACC_ID = m.Field<string>("ACCOUNT_ID_ALIAS")
});

/**Linq 2**/
userData = DisplyCustomerDetails(Convert.ToInt64(strSubAccountID));

result = serviceData.Concat(userData);
```

And another linq through function:

```
/**Function**/

System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection DisplyCustomerDetails(Int64 intAccountId)
    {
        var result = (dynamic)null;

        /** Data Display if no service avaiable **/
        IAccount_BL objAccount_BL = new Account_BL();
        Customer objCustomer = new Customer();
        DataTable dtCustomer = null;
        int intErrorCount = 0;


        objCustomer.Account_Id = Convert.ToInt64(intAccountId);

        dtCustomer =  objAccount_BL.GetCustomerDetails(objCustomer, ref intErrorCount);

        objAccount_BL = null;
        objCustomer = null;
        if (intErrorCount == 0)
        {
            if (dtCustomer != null)
            {
                if (dtCustomer.Rows.Count > 0)
                {

                    result = dtCustomer.AsEnumerable().Select(m => new
                    {
                        ACCOUNT_ID = intAccountId,
                        SUB_ACC_ID = m.Field<string>("ACCOUNT_ID_ALIAS")
                    });

                }
            }
        }

       return result;
    }
```

I wanted to join both the result of Linq1 & Linq2, I tired Concat & Union, getting below error

'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection<<>f__AnonymousTypea>' does not contain a definition for 'Concat'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To `Concat` both enumerables must of the same class; you cannot use anonymous classes.  Define a class that has the two fields and change the code to `Select` them.

Also, don't use `... = (dynamic) null`; just assign the variable directly

```
var serviceData= dtPasscode ...
var userData = DisplyCustomerDetails ...
var result = serviceData.Concat(userData);
```